# How to find at what position does a word occur in a string in C language?

Tags: arrays, c

1. Statement :You have N strings and length of each string is equal. You have to make all strings equal if possible. In one move you can choose any string, remove the first character and append it to the end of the string. You can perform this operation many times. What is the minimum number of operations that are needed to be performed to make all the strings equal? For example If you have the string `abcdef`, in one move you can transform it into the string `bcdefa`.
2. Output Format: Print the minimum number of moves you need to make all the strings equal or print  -1 if there is no solution.
3. Constraints : 1 <=T<= 10 : 1 <=N<= 50 : 1 <=str[I]<= 50

I have thought about concatenating the main string and then comparing the substring to find where it occurs at first. But I am unable to understand how to find the first occurrence. While in C++ .find() can be used, what about in C?

I have made use of 2D arrays to take input of n number of arrays.
I have made use of one more 2D array to store the concatenated strings.
I am unable to proceed further can someone please help me out how I can solve this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
  
int main() {
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    getchar();
    while (t--) {
        int i, n, j, flag, count;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        char str[n][51];
        char con[n][102];
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            scanf("%s", &str[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            strcat(con[i], str[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            strcat(con[i], str[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you heard of `strstr` and does it help for your case?

Comment: Indeed, use [strstr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr). If you need help solving the puzzle in general, then please ask a more specific question.